# Passando atributos específicos para um componente em react

Tags: javascript, react

Olá, tenho uma dúvida a respeito de como usar atributos em um componente criado em react.
Imagine que eu criei o seguinte componente:

```
const AnimatedInput = ({ label, type }) => {
    return (
        <div className='animatedInput'>
            <input  name={label} className='animatedInput__input' type={type} required />
            <span className='animatedInput__span'>{label}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Agora quando uso este componente em outra parte da minha aplicação chamo ele normalmente:

```
<AnimatedInput label={'Nome'} type={'text'}/>
```

Minha dúvida consiste em, e se eu quiser passar atributos próprios do input(por exemplo) dentro desta tag, tem como fazer isso ?

Sei que no TypeScript podemos estender estes atributos, mas no caso não estou utilizando TypeScript.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que consegui entender, você quer usar um atributo passado como props do seu componente dentro do input do component, se for isso, pode usar normalmente como referencia, por exemplo:

```
<AnimatedInput label={'Nome'} type={'text'} value={valorInput}/>
```

E dentro do component utilizar ele da mesma forma que está sendo feito no exemplo. Recebendo por parâmetro e utilizando dentro do input.

Isso responde a sua pergunta ou não entendi ela certo?

Comment: Valeu pela resposta

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o spread também (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Veja um exemplo aqui: https://codesandbox.io/s/teste-spread-np3xb?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

//seu input customizado
function MyInput({ title, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <>
      <label>{title}</label>
      <input {...rest} />
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyInput
        title="Teste"
        name="Teste"
        type="text"
        placeHolder="Testando..."
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```